# Is it a good option to simultaneously work on a game and a game engine?

Tags: c#, opengl, 3d, game-design, software-engineering

I'm considering this, now I work on 3d game but I want also to make in slow tempo, iteratively a game engine is it a good choice?
The game what I working on is with non custom engine (Unity, Unreal Engine 4 - I not yet selected, switching from engine to engine)
and also I want to develop a custom 3d engine but this engine will not be heavy but lightweight so with selected features. So I'm not talking about making Unity like engine but still 3D thank you for answer :)
And this engine will contain:

- c#
- opengl
- existing physics engine (Bullet or sth)
- ...

what I not considering:

- editor
- multiplayer
- characters

so just API
Additionally I have linear algebra background but no experience with shaders
edit: currently I want to make game in existing game engine
but in future I want to migrate with game to custom game engine

Comment: What is your previous experience? This is very opinion and situation dependent and the answers are likely to be influenced by whether this is one of your first projects or you are already a mature gamedev.

Comment: I tried Three.js, some PlayCanvas, Babylon.js
now some Godot (gdscript), Unity
generally not first project but nothing commercial related

Comment: Does the game engine or the game take priority? As in, do you want to make a game and on the way develop a game engine, or do you want to create a game engine and get a game out of it as a side effect? Is your main idea a specific game, or a specific type of a game?

Comment: the **game** takes priority, the game engine is as addition and I want to make game in existing game engine, the custom part will be some related to my game because thus I select the features for custom game engine, generally try to make game engine for racing game types

Comment: and if it will work after I want to make game in this custom engine, but this is a long term goal

Comment: I think question #1 is why do you want to make your own engine? Have you reached the limits of off-the-shelf engines? Is this purely educational? Do you hope that others will use your engine? I think you will find that your engine will cater specifically to your game and your game will be too limited by the features you don't know how to code in your engine. You claim that the game takes priority but if your engine doesn't support something which your game requires then the engine becomes a priority. You'll probably get burned out and end up with two half-baked products.

Comment: "but in future I want to migrate with game to custom game engine" - I would recommend against this. Migrating an existing project to a *newer version of the same engine* can be troublesome in many cases. Moving a game to a totally different architecture is going to result in even more trouble and a lot of duplicated work. Pick an engine and stick with it. It may be fun to get lost in engine tech, but it's not how games get finished.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Consider using a framework, like MonoGame.

It is a kind of a middle ground between "nothing" and a full-blown engine like Unity or Unreal.

It saves you from the really finicky implementation details (3d games are especially math heavy, both for graphics and physics), without dictating too much how things should be done.

Adopt a modular system - this will let you reuse parts of your game in other projects, disregarding others you may not need.

Add features to your engine incrementally as your game requires them - you can strike a balance between having your engine become the game (too specific) and having no game (too generic).

Last, but not the least, in the hopes that it would be useful, I will link my GitHub repository for a 3D game project with goals similar to yours, even if the exact game type is different. It is in no way meant as an example of a decent complete solution - but you can see it has multiple modules with common functions and solves a few common problems engines usually do for you. Consider it more of a heap of stuff to sift through and help you along an idea.

[Here it is](https://github.com/htmlcoderexe/3DGame), some lines are even commented. Note that implementing your own model system is probably not a good idea, but my terrain implementation (based on Riemers old XNA tutorials but heavily expanded) is very solid and provides nearly triangle-perfect terrain collision for cheap performance cost.

Good luck!

Comment: so use MonoGame not Unity?

Comment: I would recommend it as it is more barebones, and even though on Windows it defaults to DirectX bindings, it supports all kinds of other platforms and uses OpenGL on these. The default MonoGame template only comes with a render/update loop while all the dirty work of device initialisation and other such boilerplate has been done for you. Try it!

Comment: oh ok thx so dont start from scratch but some point

Comment: Yes, if you go too low level too fast you might get stuck on implementing things that are necessary for your game to function (like low level drawing, loading of things, timing, looping etc). It is minimalistic enough to let you build your own game engine, but still takes care of things that aren't really game-related (vector math, texture loading, there are even some basic shaders included so you can use these until you make your own).

Answer (score 16):

You, of course, can use a third party solution. You can develop C# games with (in decreasing complexity) Unity, Godot, Monogame, OpenTK, among other solutions.

**Making a game without a third party game engine** is perfectly viable. You can work with a window toolkit library, a graphics library, and so on. You will have a lot of flexibility... Yet, it is a lot of work. Because of that, it usually only makes sense for small-ish projects.

**Making a game and a game engine at the same time** is possible. You are not braking any law of physics or anything like that. However, you are likely to lose focus. The requirements of the game engine and the requirements of the game are not the same. *In particular if you are making an editor.*

I want to note that there are game framework and game IDEs. So a game framework is a game engine in the sense that it is the software component that makes the game run. *You know, like an engine.* However, often when people think about getting a "game engine", they are thinking about an editor where they can make a game, that is the game IDE.

A game IDE, a.k.a Game Engine, will allow you to build games that use a game framework, a.k.a game engine.

Thus, there are three components:

- The game
- The framework
- The IDE

You do not deploy the IDE. You deploy the game with its framework, the game won't work without the framework (they may or may not be separable on the release build).

---

Now, if you develop a game without a third party game engine. You would arguably be making the framework and the game at the same time. The problem is separating them.

You have knowledge of the game you are making while writing framework code. You could end up in a situation where the engine is not useful for a different (kind of) game, and tweaking it to be would break your old game. This happens because game specific abstractions made their way into the framework code. The more of them you put in the framework, the easier it is to make the game, and the harder it is to adapt the framework for a different game.

*The flip side is that without a game, it is hard to pin down the requirements for the framework.*

For a commercial game engine, the framework was built before the game. Thus, it does not know anything about the game. This leads naturally to a situation where the game is a plugin for the framework... and thus, switching from one game engine to another is hard. *Oh, and the companies that produce the game engines like that.* It also leads naturally to very a versatile framework. This is the state of the art. *Although not every commercial game engine is like this.*

---

Good software architecture will dictate to decouple the game. For instance, changes in the framework should not propagate to game logic. *Because of this, I’m against the framework requiring to inherit from its classes to use it.* You want to be able to make adapters with the right abstractions for the game at hand. Any change to the framework will only propagate to the adapters, and not any further. *Of course, if the framework wants inheritance, you can make the adapter inherit, and avoid placing game logic inside them.*

*Will come back to the idea of adapters.*

---

> editor

I would argue against an editor. It does not come naturally to write an IDE, unless you want to release it. What comes naturally is to make a set of tools. Each one for a specific task (such as a terrain editor, for example). And in that, you can often rely on third party solutions.

---

> multiplayer

Oh dear...

Do you mean networking? I think you mean networking. Couch multiplayer is not as popular as it used to be.

You need to decide if you are going to do any networking at all, and decide early. Having a big scary thing called network in the middle of your game will wreck your software architecture.

What kind of networking are we talking about? Will there be a central server? Will you do P2P? Should the game engine even decide that?

---

You want to isolate any external system. That includes input, network, graphics, sound, etc...

Isolating the input means, that you make an interface with whatever verbs the game needs and an adapter that implements the interface and uses some input device. If you want to support more input devices, you add more adapters.

Furthermore, who says that the input comes from an input device? It could come from a recording of inputs. This is useful for those good old game demos that arcade games did. It also useful to record a game session and replay it later. It is also useful for debugging.

In fact, who says the input comes from the same computer at all? The input could come from another player across the network!

There are two approaches that you may take around the network: send inputs, and send states. That is, you could stream every input a player does and replay them on the other side. Or you could send the state of the game objects and rebuild them on the other side. in fact, I would argue for supporting (if not using) both.

However, over which protocol? TCP? UDP? Websockets? WebRTC? How about using the Discord SDK? You know how this goes... you make an interface with the network operations the game needs, and then you implement the adapter with the underlying protocols you want. If you decide to switch protocols, you can implement another adapter.

And, yes, the same goes for physics. Perhaps you want to use Box2D, or Bullet, or PhysX... whatever, you make an interface and an adapter, you know the drill.

Similarly... OpenGl? How about DirectX or Vulkan or Metal? Well, you make... hmm... This one is trickier, because you have to deal with a shader languages. *Perhaps we can make a custom langu... wait...*

[image: xkcd: Standards]

-- [xkcd: Standards](https://xkcd.com/927/)

I'd say go full GLSL and thus OpenGL. *Screw DirectX and Metal*. And if you decide to switch to Vulkan, you can convert GLSL to SPIR-V with [KhronosGroup/glslang](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glslang).

With that said, you probably should still make an adapter for OpenGL, and expose an interface that understand loading models and scenes instead of buffers and draw calls. You may also want it to compose shader programs.

---

I don't want to tell you here what to do about your game loop, or whatever or not you should use ECS, or stuff like that. You can research and figure what you want.

However, you should have a set of interfaces under you control, which the game can use to work. Keeping the game code free from details about the hardware or the libraries that the framework uses.

To pick what adapter to use should depend on configuration. You are going to need a [composition root](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/).

*Oh, do not forget some good infrastructure: error handling, logging, loading and saving configuration, etc.*

Thus, by virtue of software architecture we can distinguish:

- The game
- The interfaces
- The adapters
- The framework
- The composition root
- The IDE or other tools

You can choose to make modules like this, for example:

- The game
- The framework, composition root, interfaces and adapters
- The IDE or other tools

*The company that makes the engine is in control.*

That is not what software architecture would suggest, but it leaves the less work to develop the game module, while tying the game to the engine. *Like the company likes it.* You do not have to do it like that, bundle them however you want.

---

Finally, I want to recommend the video: [Write a Game Engine? - WHY and HOW.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gf5mMWHWNYc)

Comment: yes I mean networking

Comment: what do you think about V language it looks promising should I make with it instead of c#?

Comment: @grzesiekmq I was unaware of V. I had a look at what it offers, and I do not think it is ready. C# is pretty good, the compiler has improved a lot. I understand that people think it will be slow. If that is the concern, you may want to looking into making native images with .NET. Furthermore, the more you do in shaders the less the performance of the main language matters. Now... if you want something closer to C, I suggest Rust, see arewegameyet.com - by the way, you could have modules in different languages. How about some ZeroMQ? You can go crazy. Which brings me to this: use what you know.